# Why my maven installation is slow?

Tags: maven

I downloaded maven, unzipped it into a dir, and added Java_Home, Maven_Home, M2_Home, but when I did a "mvn -v" at command line, it would take several minutes for it to come back with the version info. No error message, just slow. I have a win 7 running Java7 & Java8, I tried both, same.

I ran it from my PC, it's local, why ? How to fix ?

Comment: The maven install is just a bootstrap. When maven runs for the first time it downloads its components as plugins from the Maven Central website. You should only see the performance hit once because Maven caches plugins locally. If you have  a lot of client installs to perform you could improve performance by running a local Maven repository using something like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on VPN, once I turned it off, it works fine.

Comment: It's an alternative but not a real solution. Consider we must have a VPN turned on for working, how to make Maven faster ?